# Association fail with doctrine mapping Doctrine 2

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, mapping, associations

I've got the following problem with doctrine 2, i want to join my adress entity and country entity to my user entity. So after some tries it works fine in the database, but when i use `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema` 
it shows me some fails at the mapping.

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'User\Entity\Adress' mapping is invalid:
* The association User\Entity\Adress#user refers to the inverse side field User\Entity\User#use
r_id which does not exist.
* The association User\Entity\Adress#country refers to the inverse side field User\Entity\Count
ry#id which is not defined as association.
* The association User\Entity\Adress#country refers to the inverse side field User\Entity\Count
ry#id which does not exist.
```

I really don't know why this happened, because my database works fine like this. It recognize the user and country entity in adress, and also the values.

My user entity:

```
   ...
    /**
 * Entity Class representing a post of our User module.
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="User\Repository\UserRepository")
 * 
 * @property int userid
 * @property string firstname
 * @property string insertion
 * @property string lastname
 * @property date dateofbirth
 * @property string gender
 * @property string phonenumber
 * @property string mobile
 */
    class User extends zfcUser implements UserInterface
    {
        /**
         * Id from user
         * 
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Adress", mappedBy="user", cascade= "remove")
         * @access protected
         */

        /**
         * Firstname of our user
         *
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
         * @var string
         * @access protected
         */
        protected $firstname;

    ...
    ...
```

My adress entity:

```
/**
 * Entity Class representing our Adress module.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="adress")
 * @property integer addressid
 * @property string street
 * @property integer number
 * @property string addition
 * @property string zipcode
 * @property integer userid
 * @property integer countryid
 */
class Adress
{

...
...

/** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="user_id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     * @var User[]
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var Country[]
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $country;

...
...
```

My country entity:

```
   ...
    ...
    /**
 * Entity Class representing our Country module.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="country")
 * @property integer id
 * @property string countrycode
 * @property string countryname
 */
    class Country
    {
    /**
         * Id from a country
         * 
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Adress", mappedBy="country")
         * @var int
         * @access protected
         */
        protected $id;

    ...
    ...
```

Someone an explanation why this happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first error:

In your `User` class the property which is in relation to address is missing, so there might be two possibilities:

1. If its `protected $user_id`:
   This won't work because Doctrine expects an array of address objects at this place.
2. If its `protected $addresses`:
   You have to change the mapping in your `Address` class on the user property to:

   `@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="addresses")`

For the second error:

In your `Address` class you have to remove the inversedBy attribute on country:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country")
```

Comment: Oke, second problem solved. But my first error not. I've a protected $user_id in my userclass.. But it is extended by the zfcUser (where this $user_id is set). I want the user_id's in my address (because a user can have multiple addresses). How can i fix that error?

Comment: Just call your OneToMany property in `User` class $adresses, you need the $user_id too, but when it's in zfcUser and this class is a mapped superclass it should work.